# When to use 一倍 vs 两倍

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would like to have a clarification on this: I know that 倍 means "-times, -fold", but I don't understand why 一倍 seems to mean "twice as (fast)" in the following sentence:

开车最少比骑自行车快一倍。

while we have to use 两倍 in the following sentences:

8是4的两倍。
X贵两倍。

I don't know how to tag this question so feel free to change it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If some words that mean "is" (e.g **是/相当于** ) are used, then it's literal times.

你的速度 **是** 我的两倍。

Your speed **is** twice **as** mine.

Normally you will not say "one times" in this scenario. 你的速度是我的一倍 (Your speed is one times as mine) sounds strange in both English and Chinese. You can just say "你的速度和我的一样快"/ “我们俩一样快" (You are as fast as me).

If other "comparing" words that means "more than"(e.g. A **比** B 大/高/快/etc.) show, then it's literal times + 1. Followed one has the same meaning of previous one.

你的速度 **比** 我快一倍。

You **are** one time faster **than** me.

Answer (score 4):

**一倍**

**Tuttle's Learners**

> fold, time
>
> 这个学校的学生人数比我们学校多一倍。(=这个学校的学生人数是我们学校的两倍。)
>
> Zhège xuéxiào de xuésheng rénshù bǐ wǒmen xuéxiào duō yí bèi. (= Zhège xuéxiào de xuésheng rénshù shì wǒmen xuéxiào de liǎng bèi.)
> The student number of this school is twice as big as that of our school. (—> The student population of this school is twice of ours.)

多一倍 is translated, first in Chinese as 两倍 so it's easy to see how confusing this phrasing is! But....

**两倍**

**Oxford**

> ② [indicating difference in quantity]
>
> 这一带水稻产量比小麦高两倍
>
> The output of rice is three times that of wheat in this area

两倍 has become **three times** here(!).

**but**(!) - still from *Oxford*:

> 你的工资相当于我的两倍。
>
> Your salary is twice that of mine.

Basically you've really got to look at the context to figure out the meaning!

Your sentence above
`开车最少比骑自行车快一倍。` the 快 here has the same effect as 多 so it's really saying it's "one time as fast" which is really "twice as fast"...

Hope that makes sense

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, 比骑自行车快一倍 is not saying it's "one time as fast" but "one time faster", which is legitimately equivalent to "twice as fast".

Answer (score 4):

Understand that you have an accpeted answer already and it's correct.  I am adding this in hope to make it simple to understand:

一倍 : 100%
两倍 : 200%

They are the same.  So when you are saying 快一倍, it means `100% faster`, or `twice the speed`, which means 200% of the origin speed - 两倍速度.  The confusion comes in because when 一倍 is used, we `ADD` the value by itself, while 两倍 we `MULTIPLE` the value by 2.  And we all know that A + A (一倍) = 2A (两倍)

Comment: This is exactly what I deduced from the accepted answer. That's a nice way of putting it though.

Answer (score 1):

I think the more correct way to use 一倍/兩倍 is answered by user3306356 and Caff Huang.

But, in most contexts, 快一倍 and 快兩倍 have just same meaning. Because if we use 快兩倍 as "x * 3", the meaning will be too vague to understand.

If we really have to say something larger than two times of a value, such as "A = B * 3", a more practical way will be "A是B的3倍" instead of "A比B高兩倍".