# Saying 'doubled' in Chinese 一倍 vs 两倍

Tags: characters, simplified-characters, comparison

I stumbled upon these 2 sentences:

`这个城市人口比十年前增加了一倍`

`这个城市人口比十年前增加了两倍`

`The city’s population has doubled from a decade ago`

I though `倍` always multiplies the number standing in front of it, it seems like in case of `一`

How come? Is there any logical explanation?

Comment: 这个城市人口比十年前增加了一倍 = 这个城市人口是十年前的两倍, 这个城市人口比十年前增加了两倍 = 这个城市人口是十年前的三倍.

Comment: users suggest suspecting existence at this site of previous discussions of this matter, searching site seems to confirm such suspicion, see esp. https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/9295/when-to-use-%e4%b8%80%e5%80%8d-vs-%e4%b8%a4%e5%80%8d

Answer (score 4):

Technically, when you say "增加了n倍", "n倍" is describing the *difference* the two number. So the original `x` becomes `x*(n+1)`, while the difference is `n*x`.

If you want to say that the latter number is just `n` times the former, then it is "增加**到**了(原来的)n倍"

However, in casual speech, people may not always respect this rule, which makes it confusing. Sometimes we have to make a confirmation to make sure we get the real number.

Answer (score 2):

They both express doubled.

It’s a bit like how:

- a 100% increase (一倍)

is the same as

- a two-fold increase (两倍)

A phenomenon that is equally confusing in English.

---

Compare: **一倍** example sentences from *ABC*

> 这座城市将要扩展一倍。 
>   Zhè ⁴zuò chéngshì jiāngyào kuòzhǎn yị̄ ²bèi.
>   This city will double its size.
>
> 学生人数增加了一倍。 
>   Xuésheng rénshù zēngjiāle yị̄ ²bèi.
>   The number of students has doubled.

and **两倍** example sentences from *Tuttle*

> 他的收人是三年前的两倍。 
>   Tā de shōurén shì sān nián qián de liǎng bèi.
>   His income is double what it was three years ago.
>
> 他现在挣的钱是先前工作的两倍。 
>   Tā xiànzài zhèng de qián shì xiānqián gōngzuò de liǎng bèi.
>   He's earning twice as much as in his previous job.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between  扩展/增加n倍 and X是Y的n倍？

Comment: @dan Of course. Unless I misunderstood the question I believe that OP's issue is how 一倍 and 两倍 can mean the same thing. So I decided to use this angle to show how they both mean double.

Answer (score 1):

Math:

倍 means multiple X * 1,

增加了一倍 means x + x * 1,

增加了2 倍 means x + x * 2

某某是它的2倍  means 某某 =  x * 2

某某是它的1倍 means 某某 = x * 1, = x.

So, 我的分数是你的一倍 imply scores are equal technically.

The right one should be 我的分数比你多一倍.

Answer (score 1):

倍 is *time* in English. However, there are few expressions/phrases that can make difference when they are used in a sentence. I try to summarize a bit:

1. X 比 Y 增加n倍: X = Y*(n+1);
2. X 是 Y 的n倍: X = Y*n;
3. X 比 Y 多n倍: X = Y*(n+1);

Those phrases are clear and will not cause any confusion.

In fact, the most confusing phrase is X 比 Y翻n倍. Some take it as X = Y*n, some think X = Y*(n+1), and some even think X = Y* 2^n. I indeed don't have any official answer for this so far.